# Segmenting cursive character (Arabic OCR)

Tags: matlab, ocr, image-segmentation

I want to segment an Arabic word into single characters. Based on the histogram/profile, I assume that I can do the segmentation process by cut/segment the characters based on it's baseline (it have similar pixel values). 
But, unfortunately, I still stuck to build the appropriate code, to make it works.

```
% Original Code by Soumyadeep Sinha 
% Saving each  single segmented character as one file 
function [segm] = trysegment (a)
 myFolder = 'D:\1. Thesis FINISH!!!\Data set\trial';
 level = graythresh (a);
 bw = im2bw (a, level);
 b = imcomplement (bw);
 i= padarray(b,[0 10]);
 verticalProjection = sum(i, 1);
 set(gcf, 'Name', 'Trying Segmentation for Cursive', 'NumberTitle', 'Off') 
 subplot(2, 2, 1);imshow(i); 
 subplot(2,2,3);
 plot(verticalProjection, 'b-'); %histogram show by this code
% hist(reshape(input,[],3),1:max(input(:))); 
 grid on;
 % % t = verticalProjection;
 % % t(t==0) = inf;
 % % mayukh = min(t)
% 0 where there is background, 1 where there are letters
 letterLocations = verticalProjection > 0; 
 % Find Rising and falling edges
 d = diff(letterLocations);
 startingColumns = find(d>0);
 endingColumns = find(d<0);
% Extract each region
 y=1;
 for k = 1 : length(startingColumns)
  % Get sub image of just one character...
    subImage = i(:, startingColumns(k):endingColumns(k)); 
%   se = strel('rectangle',[2 4]);
%   dil = imdilate(subImage, se); 
  th = bwmorph(subImage,'thin',Inf);
  n = imresize (th, [64 NaN], 'bilinear');
  figure, imshow (n);  
[L,num] = bwlabeln(n);
for z= 1 : num
bw= ismember(L, z);
% Construct filename for this particular image.
 baseFileName = sprintf('char %d.png', y);
 y=y+1;
% Prepend the folder to make the full file name.
 fullFileName = fullfile(myFolder, baseFileName);
% Do the write to disk.
 imwrite(bw, fullFileName);
% subplot(2,2,4);
% pause(2);
% imshow(bw);
end
% y=y+1;
end;
segm = (n);
```

Word image is as follow:
[image: <code>Segmenting cursive character</code>]

Why the code isn't work? 
do you have any recommendation of another codes? 
or suggested algorithm to make it works, to do a good segmentation on cursive character?

Thanks before.

Comment: What is the dimension of matrix `verticalProjection`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this code part from the posted code

```
% 0 where there is background, 1 where there are letters
 letterLocations = verticalProjection > 0; 
 % Find Rising and falling edges
 d = diff(letterLocations);
 startingColumns = find(d>0);
 endingColumns = find(d<0);
```

with the new code part

```
threshold=max(verticalProjection)/3;
thresholdedProjection=verticalProjection > threshold;
count=0;
startingColumnsIndex=0;
for i=1:length(thresholdedProjection)
    if thresholdedProjection(i)
        if(count>0)
            startingColumnsIndex=startingColumnsIndex+1;
            startingColumns(startingColumnsIndex)= i-floor(count/2);
            count=0;
        end
    else
        count=count+1;
    end
end
endingColumns=[startingColumns(2:end)-1 i-floor(count/2)];
```

No changes needed for the rest of the code.

Comment: sorry for a late respond @Rijul. I need a help again. I get an error: 
.
Error in segm
  subImage = i(:, startingColumns(k):endingColumns(k));

.

What I am supposed to do?

Comment: Thank you so much @RijulSudhir. It works, after several modification. Could you tell how the code works? A proper explanation. Because, I think, I still need some modification to meet my expectation result.

Comment: could you please explain, why threshold = max (verticalProjection)/3? || Because i have great data image, and the images contain various threshold, it's still not successful for all image. The codes, doesn't suit for all images yet.

Could you explain me more about the code, so i could define, what i should do to fix the problem. Thank you